# Specify timezone in ToDate(unix) in Pig

Tags: datetime, unix, apache-pig

In my dataset I have dates in Unix timestamps. I want to convert these to a datetime in Apache Pig. For this I can use the `ToDate()` function as described [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/func.html#to-date). However I know my Unix timestamps to be in GMT / UTC, but converting using `ToDate()` will result in my local timezone. I don't see how I can specify the timezone in this function when converting from a Unix timestamp. I don't want to manually adjust the datetime after conversion, because this is a huge pain with daylight savings time. Hopefully someone has a good suggestion, every help will be appreciated.

Here an example:

```
ToString( ToDate( (long)'1417145524000'), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss' )
```

results in (2014-11-28 04:04:32) which is the time in CET, however I want this to be (2014-11-28 03:04:32) in GMT.

Comment: `1417145524000` is July 21st, 46877

Comment: strange, in my case Pig does exactly the opposite: it shows the date in +0000 timezone, but I want local and don't know how to force it.

BTW, I'm pretty sure you meant 'yyyy-MM-dd **HH**:ss:mm', as lowecase h will only give you hours from 1 to 12.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you're looking for:

```
ToDate(userstring, format, timezone)
```

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#to-date

Timezone stings:
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html

After Edwin's comment:

In this specific case you can to do this:

```
ToDate(ToString(ToDate((long) ts), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:mm'), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:mm', 'timezone')
```

Comment: That works with a userstring (chararray) to date, but not with a long in miliseconds as I have, I think. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you're right, I just added the work-a-round into the answer, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note, that Pig's ToDate uses offset-only timezones - how many hours + or - of GMT.
Not the geographical ones. You can run into troubles with daylight saving times in this way.
Consider computing time differences in hours since midnight:

`2015-03-29 03:00:00+0200 minus 2015-03-29 00:00:00+0100 is 4 hours`

but

`2015-03-29 03:00:00+0200 (Europe/Prague) minus 2015-03-29 00:00:00+0100 (Europe/Prague) is 3 hours.`

With Pig's ToDate, you can only achieve the former behavior.