# PIG - convert input date into UTC timezone

Tags: hadoop, timezone, apache-pig, utc

I have an input file with date in PST format

```
example => 2014-02-04 05:46:36.0
```

I need to have a pig syntax to convert this date into UTC.I tried using ToDate(input_date_column,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS','UTC') but it did not work.

```
Error shown - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: ""2014-02-04 05:46:36.0""
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I already answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757636/specify-timezone-in-todateunix-in-pig/33769314#33769314

Answer (score 1):

i could not really find some in build method for this one

so i wrote an user defined function and used it into my pig script

it goes like this -

```
public class convertToUTC extends EvalFunc<String> {
        @Override
        public String exec(final Tuple input) throws IOException {
            if (input == null || input.size() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            try {
                String date = input.get(0).toString();
                Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(date);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(timestamp);
                calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
                Timestamp UTCTimestamp = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
                return UTCTimestamp.toString();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
            }
        }
    }
```