# How to convert unix time in seconds to UTC time format YYYYMMDDHH in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to convert unix time in seconds to UTC time in the format of `YYYYMMDDHH` within pig script. I've tried  `ToDate` and `ToString` but can't figure it out.

Sample Data: `1464797936`

expecting the output as: `2016060116`

Comment: This post may be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757636/specify-timezone-in-todateunix-in-pig

Comment: I tried but it gives me local time and not UTC time. My data comes from multiple time zones and they all get converted to local time of the m/c.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ToString(ToDate(timestamp * 1000L), 'yyyyMMddHH')
```

Comment: Thanks.
I'm getting the following error while trying to run:
out_data = FOREACH test_data GENERATE ToString(ToDate(ts * 1000L, 'yyyyMMdd'));
ts defined as long
ERROR 1045:
Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Comment: Sorry, added missing parenthesis

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting the following error while trying to run: out_data = FOREACH test_data GENERATE ToString(ToDate(ts * 1000L, 'yyyyMMdd')); BTW, ts defined as long. ERROR 1045: Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Comment: Please look at the code snippet again. There should be closing parenthesis after 1000L.

Comment: But this gives me local time and I need GMT/UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

```
ToString(ToDate((long)timestamp * 1000L), 'yyyyMMddHH', 'timezone')
```

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#to-date

Timezone stings: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html

For more details, please refer to SO answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33769314/786676

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674306/786676